# How to restore backup from Google Drive

Tags: tablet, sony-xperia, google-drive

I've a Sony Xperia Z tablet (SGP311) that has a specific setting to enable online backups. It reads (translated from Spanish):

> Back up application data, wifi passwords and other settings in Google servers

I wanted to do a factory reset to clean up storage so I enabled it and I waited several hours until the copy showed in Google Drive (my tablet lacks the "Backup up data now" mentioned in generic Google documentation).

After the factory reset, the wizard never offered to restore any copy. I added the Google account to the device but absolutely no data has been restored. There's no option anywhere to restore the copy. This is utterly different from my experience with an LG phone, where everything (and I mean everything) was restored automatically upon first star up.

I have two questions:

- Did I misunderstand the purpose of Google backups in the context of Xperia?
- Is there a way to restore the backup I have in Google Drive?

<sub>*(Additionally, I copied into my desktop PC all files and folders that are possible to copy though USB and I made a backup with Xperia Companion.
 As last resource, I tried restoring the Companion backup—the program runs for a while and then closes unexpectedly... but I guess that's another question.)*</sub>

Comment: Regarding second question, this may help https://android.stackexchange.com/q/191320/131553

Comment: I've given up on Drive's backup. I eventually managed to restore the Companion one—it's as simple as running it several times until it doesn't crash. As advertised, it just contains media files and little else, so I had to create all users from scratch, install apps from Google Play's collection and configure them one by one. You can trigger intallations from a desktop browser (some users receive them, some don't, no idea why). I'll leave the question open in case someone comes in with information that can help others.