# Google Drive backup not showing

Tags: contacts, backup, restore, google-backup

I switched phones a while back but just noticed that even if im logged in with the same google account, I am not able to access my previous phone's backup. These are the backups in my GDrive:

[image: Google Backups]

I need the Alcatel backup. But when I go to Settings → Google → Restore Contacts, these are the ones that come up:

[image: IMG:]

(Tap to enlarge)

The Alcatel backup which is the one that I need is not showing up. Why is this? How can I restore this backup?

Comment: Was the Alcatel back up of a different Android version while others are of same version? If yes, reason *may be* this (guessing) [Why is my Android not restoring the app data from its Google Drive backup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/197511)